Flutter Cannot Build Application used iOS 18 and Xcode 16
Running pod install...                                             651ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `device_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`
Warning: firebase_app_id_file.json file does not exist. This may cause issues in upload-symbols. If this error is unexpected, try running flutterfire configure again.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_app_version_checker` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_app_version_checker/ios`
[!] Invalid podspec file at path
`/Users/abdullahghanayem/StudioProjects/menatracks/ios/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_app_version_checker/ios/flutter_app_version_checker.podspec`.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:755:in `block in from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:752:in `chdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:752:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:733:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:164:in `store_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:17:in `block in fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:997:in `fetch_external_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:976:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:974:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your
Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15.
flutter clean
cd ios
pod install

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Update your PodFile with: platform :ios, '14.0'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.25.0'
pod install --repo-update
